# How change to the NaN type?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a data set that contains '-' and 'na' value. How to convert the data that are considered missing values to NAN by using the na_values attribute?

```
df = pd.read_csv('austin_weather.csv'.na_values==['na','-'])
```

Comment: This is a typo. `.` should be `,` and `na_values==` should be `na_values=`

Comment: You need to replace the `.` with `,` and the `==` with `=` in the read_csv - but otherwise your approach seems fine

Comment: `NaN` is not a type but a value.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Jeffrey Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8550657/jeffrey-ram) and [Mortz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4248842/mortz) explained in the comments, [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) arguments need to be separated by a comma `,` and values have to be assigned by the equals sign `=`:

Use this instead :

```
df = pd.read_csv('austin_weather.csv', na_values=['na','-'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is not correct, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

# test.csv:
# h1;h2;h3;h4
# test1;test2;-;na
    
# this is an incorrect syntax:
# df = pd.read_csv('test.csv'.na_values==['na','-'])
# >> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'na_values'

# correct usage of pandas read_csv():
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values=['na','-'], sep=';')
pprint(df)
# >>    h1     h2    h3  h4
# >> 0  test1  test2 NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
df = df.replace('na', np.nan).replace('-', np.nan)
```